# How To Remove Unnecessary Margin From Right Side Of My Web site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, margin

My WordPress Website Using Quidus Theme contains unnecessary space from the right which looks very bad. Please help: How can I remove this space? I want my web pages to fill the whole screen. There is no margin needed on the right or left sides.

[Look at the image provided below of my website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nILRg.png)

[My Website Link is here](http://theme.socialflag.net/latest-free-wordpress-themes/)

Note: I want all posts to fit the screen full width.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure is:

```
<div id="page">
  <div class="site-content"></div>
  <div class="right-sidebar-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Your CSS is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 955px) {
  .site {
    max-width: 1718px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1105px) {
  .site-content {
    width: 56%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1105px) and (min-width: 955px) {
  .site-content {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .right-sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 480px) {
  .right-sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1105px) and (min-width: 955px) {
  .right-sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1105px) {
  .right-sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 22%;
  }
}
```

The problem with your CSS is `.site-content` and `.right-sidebar-wrapper` width don't make it 100% of their parent.

Let's clarify:

- at window width > 1105px `.site-content` = 56% while `.right-sidebar-wrapper` = 22% so 56% + 22% = 78% but 100% - 78% = 22% which is where the margin comes from at this resolution
- at window width > 955 and < 1105 `.site-content` = 70% and `.right-sidebar-wrapper` = 70% which makes your right sidebar display below `.site-content` because 70% + 70% = 140% so `#page` can't contain at at the same line

To solve this change `.site-content` and `.right-sidebar-wrapper` CSS rules for their width so they take 100% of their parent's width at resolutions you want them to display next to each other.

Possible solution is to change:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1105px) {
  .site-content {
    width: 56%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1105px) and (min-width: 955px) {
  .right-sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

to:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1105px) {
  .site-content {
    width: 78%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1105px) and (min-width: 955px) {
  .right-sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```